# Convert json to string array of arrays in Apple Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am writing my first Swift program (Swift 5.1) using Xcode.

I am struggling. All I want to do is convert a json string into two arrays of arrays. A good tutorial is here https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37 but it is just too complex.

An example json string is below.

```
{
  "Animals" :
  {
   "Mice" : ["Mickey", "Minnie"],
   "Ducks" : ["Donald", "Daisy"],
   "Elephants" : ["Dumbo", "Yzma"]
  },
  "Movies" :
  {
   "1940s" : ["Pinocchio", "Fantasia", "Dumbo"],
   "1950s" : ["Cinderella", "Treasure Island", "Peter Pan"],
   "1960s" : ["The Signs of Zorro", "Swiss Family Robinson", "Mary Poppins"],
   "1970s" : ["Herbie Rides Again", "Herbie Goes to Monte Carlo", "Freaky Friday"] 
  }
}
```

All I want is minimal crappy code that I can paste into a Swift playground to creates two arrays of arrays so in arrayAnimal[0][1] is Minnie, arrayAnimal[2][0] is Dumbo, and arrayMovie[3][1] is Herbie Goes to Monte Carlo for example.

If it is possible use arrayAnimal["mice"][1] to get Minnie this is perfect, but for now my focus is working out how I should deserialize the json in Swift to get the arrays of arrays.

Thank you

Comment: This should help, https://quicktype.io/ . Dump that JSON into the editor, select `swift` from the language selector and does all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need this codable model for your json. you should add it in separate swift file:

```
  struct MyModel: Codable {
    let animals: Animals
    let movies: [String: [String]]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Animals
        case Movies
    }
}

// MARK: - Animals
struct Animals: Codable {
    let mice, ducks, elephants: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Mice
        case Ducks
        case Elephants
    }
```

}

then you need to convert your string to Data :

```
let jsonData: Data? = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
```

then you can easily decode your data to desired object.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let myModel= try decoder.decode(MyModel.self, from: jsonData)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

in the end you can access your desired data through your decoded object.
for example :

```
let anArrayOfStringsOfMices = myModel.animals.mice
```

Comment: It works! Thank you, simple yet I would still be working on it if left to my own devices

Comment: @Steve  glad to hear. it would be great to check my answer and upvote it :)